# Is it possible to run 2 different agents at the same time

Tags: lotus-notes

In IBM Notes I have 2 agents on 1 server, 1 on database A and one on database B. Agent on Database A copies forms to  Server 2 and agent on database B copies forms with the same form-name also to Server 2. So eventually on Server 2 I have 1 view where I can access all these documents.

1 agent takes time to run so that it can copy all documents to Server 2. My question is, is it possible to run on server 1 the 2 agents at the same time?

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear: OF COURSE you can run multiple agents at the same time... Your problem might be, chat these agents do not "interfere", as they write the same kind of documents. And please: be CLEAR in your descriptions. I am sure, that your agents do NOT copy forms (=design elements), but documents with the same form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domino's Agent Manager can be configured to allow many agents to run at the same time. I believe the [default setting](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/othr_servertasksagentmanagertab_r.html) is just one at a time during the day and two at a time at night, but this is routinely changed by server administrators. At all times, it allows only one scheduled or new/edited documents agent *per database* to run simultaneously, but there are various other ways to trigger agents so that many will be running even though they are in the same database. Web agents, for example, aren't run under the control of the Agent Manger, and mail-triggered agents are not either, so they are not subject to this restriction.

Comment: Domino server is capable of running many Scheduled Agents simultaneously, but CPU and I/O are common bottlenecks. Keep an eye on those two and you are good to go.